# Why the size of array is calculated incorrectly when done from inside a function?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, sizeof

When I use this code in the `main()` function, the size (or length) of the array is calculated correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 5};
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("The number of elements in the array is %d\n", length);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The number of elements in the array is 10
```

But when I do the same thing by using a function, then the output is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sizeTeller(int array[]);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 5};
    printf("The number of elements in the array is %d\n", sizeTeller(arr));
    return 0;
}

int sizeTeller(int array[])
{
    int len;
    return (len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

Output:

```
The number of elements in the array is 2
```

Can you please explain this to me that why this is so? I prefer to keep all the codes in functions that's why I tried the same here but the output went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, like for many other cases<sup>NOTE</sup>, when arrays are passed as a function argument, they decay to the pointer to the first element of the array. Hence, in the called function, the received parameter type is a pointer, not an array.

So, in case of

```
int sizeTeller(int array[])
{
    int len;
    return (len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

is equivalent as

```
int sizeTeller(int* array)
{
    int len;
    return (len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));  // sizeof (int *) / sizeof (int)
}
```

**Solution:** If you need to pass an array as a function argument, and need to know it's size, you need to calculate the size in the caller and pass that as another argument to the called function.

---

NOTE:

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.3.2.1/P3

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type *'array of type'* is converted to an expression with type *'pointer to type'* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [....]

Comment: does that mean that the `sizeof(arr)` which is in the `main()` is calculating the size of full array. I mean `arr` is also a pointer to the first element of the array so why it didn't returned the size of a pointer to `int`, as it would have done in `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder No, note the "like many other cases" part, it's not "always". I'll expand the answer a bit to clarify.

Comment: I got your point and understood the reason for wrong output. But just clear me this that `arr` being a pointer to the first element of the array (as in `main()` function) then why the `sizeof(arr)` don't return `8 bytes`, which is the size of the pointer to int.

Comment: Did you read the latest edit? It specifically says **except** scenarios, `sizeof` operator is one of them.